# Lenovo IdeaPad G560 BIOS on an external display

Tags: laptop, bios, lenovo-laptop, external-display, laptop-display

I had an accident and my laptop screen was completely unusable, the rest of the components work properly because I connected an external monitor to check it.

The problem is that I cannot access the BIOS, the external monitor does not show anything until the operating system starts. I already tried the following solutions

1. Disconnect the flex cable from the monitor
2. Press and hold the fn + f2 / f3 key (key for switching display) during startup

Nothing seems to work.

Comment: If you remove the HDD/SSD, it will automatically load into BIOS. If you still don't see anything, then this particular model has no possibility of using external monitors for the BIOS. Have you tried both the VGA and the HDMI?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, my laptop only have vga port. I tried removing the hard drive but still getting nothing on the external display

Comment: Did you try pressing Fn+F3 when the screen is blank? You sometimes need to select an external monitor manually. Try out Fn+F3 or Fn+F4 which should be the small monitor icon on your keyboard.

Comment: Yes I did it, but if I'm prompted with a selection menu I cannot see it because it isn't displayed on the external monitor

Comment: I mean: Fn+F3/F4 should enable the external monitor even in the selection menu and the bios. Check with a second monitor as well, it might not like the low resolution of the bios.  If there's still no display then there's nothing to do, the BIOS is only available on the internal display.

Comment: Yes, I tried with those keys several times, I tried both of them just after turning on the laptop and also a few seconds after. But as I mentioned, nothing shows on the external display. I've to assumed as you said that the BIOS is only available for the internal display. Edit: I don't have another display to try, this one works just fine with my desktop pc

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting the internal LVDS cable, just in case?

Comment: Yes, I removed the internal display completely (cables, case, broken lcd, everything)

Answer (score -1):

I just post what worked for me.

just close the lid for a while, so it seems that it doesn't detect the its own monitor, hence send the signal to the external monitor :)